# How to get multiple lists out of one by comma separated list?

Tags: python, list, split

I've got a list which looks like this:

```
List = [('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:19.004125', '1'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:20.893915', '2'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:22.497974', '3'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:23.785106', '4'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:25.324855', '5'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:26.985723', '6'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:28.866707', '7'),
        ('TestID', '2020-02-03 17:16:30.477464', '8')]
```

I want to split this list into 3 lists which should look like this:

```
List1 = ['TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID`', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID']
List2 = ['2020-02-03 17:16:19.004125', '2020-02-03 17:16:20.893915',
         '2020-02-03 17:16:22.497974', '2020-02-03 17:16:23.785106',
         '2020-02-03 17:16:25.324855', '2020-02-03 17:16:26.985723',
         '2020-02-03 17:16:28.866707', '2020-02-03 17:16:30.477464']
List3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Can somebody tell me how I can do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: just check how you can get transpose matrix of the given matrix.you will find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to index out of your subelements to create new lists.

```
>>> [i[0] for i in List]                        
['TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID', 'TestID']

>>> [i[1] for i in List]
['2020-02-03 17:16:19.004125', '2020-02-03 17:16:20.893915', '2020-02-03 17:16:22.497974', '2020-02-03 17:16:23.785106', '2020-02-03 17:16:25.324855', '2020-02-03 17:16:26.985723', '2020-02-03 17:16:28.866707', '2020-02-03 17:16:30.477464']

>>> [i[2] for i in List]                                    
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` with unpacking here.

```
l1,l2,l3=zip(*List)
```

> Note: `l1,l2,l3` are tuples typecast them to `list`.

Or you can use `map` to convert them to `list`.

```
l1,l2,l3=map(list,zip(*List))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L1=[]
for i in range(3):
    temp=[]
    temp=[j[i] for j in List]
    L1.append(temp)
```

You can access by indexing L1